# Android - how to get ListView to line up underneath Text View

Tags: android, layout

I am attempting to put a ListView beneath a Text View in an Android App. However, the first line of the ListView shows up on the same line as the TextView. How do I get this to move underneath?

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:question"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dummy_question" />    
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_notes"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is only that in linearlayout put:

`android:orientation=vertical`

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html). [Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues. First, as chirag mentioned, you need to set the ListView orientation. Second, a listView cannot 'wrap content' for height. What would it wrap to? One row, two? Basically, a listView has no idea how tall you want it to be. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/android:question"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dummy_question" />    
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0px" android:layout_weight="1" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_notes"/>
</LinearLayout>
```